# List of latest actions per group

Tags: django

I have following models in Django (PostgreSQL):

```
class Action(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    verb = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    target_object_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)


class Notification(models.Model):
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notifications')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_readed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Can you help me with building notification feed for a user? A query should return the latest actions for the particular recipient, but do not duplicate actions for the same target_object_id.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: With a ForeignKey you can only store one action. Is that on purpose?

Comment: I am using Postgres. One action can generate several Notifications to recipients (aka subscribers). With this app, I am currently in the design phase, so if it would help I can change the model structure or add some auxiliary fields to perform optimal db query.